# Does testing assure bug free product?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, test-management

Is it **Possible or impossible** to do a 100% testing?

We had tested an application and solved all critical or major bugs, but after some time we found some functionality bugs in it.

So my question is, is it possible to deliver bug free applications?

Comment: Can you add more details? narrow it down to a specific problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on complexity, but in most cases there is no time to make exhaustive testing. 100 % bug free product cannot be guaranteed.

> Consider an application in which a password field that accepts 3
>   characters, with no consecutive repeating entries. Hence, there are 26
>   * 26 * 26 input permutations for alphabets only. Including special characters and standard characters, there are much more combinations.
>   So, there are 256 * 256 * 256 input combinations.

via tutorialspoint